# Can you explain why debounce does this binding?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, debouncing

```
function debounce(fn, delay) {
    var timer
    return function () {
      var context = this
      var args = arguments
      clearTimeout(timer)
      timer = setTimeout(function () {
        fn.apply(context, args)
      }, delay)
    }
  }
```

1. I'm curious about the purpose of context = this in this code. I don't understand the code very well.
2. Secondly, fn.apply (context, args) This part is also not well understood. Is there a special reason to bind this? You want to use the debounce function as an util function throughout the project.

```
export function debounce(fn, delay) {
  var timer;
  return function () {
    var args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
      fn.apply(this, args);
    }, delay);
  };
}
```

3. I want to know the difference between the last chord and the first chord

Comment: it applies `context` (i.e. the saved `this`) to be the `this` for calling `fn`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `var context = this`

The reason why you would put [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) into a different variable in this code is simply that
[`function(){}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) has a different `this` value based on where it gets called. In this case it's called from `setTimeout` as a callback, which means that `this` would be whatever it is inside of `setTimeout` instead of what it was when the debounce inner function was called

You could get around this pretty easily in modern JavaScript using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which have a lexical `this` - `this` is based on *where* the function was created instead of where it is called.

This would be the equivalent code to the initial version with the correct `this` binding.

```
function debounce(fn, delay) {
    var timer
    return function () {
      var args = arguments
      clearTimeout(timer)
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        fn.apply(this, args)
      }, delay)
    }
  }
```

2. `fn.apply(context, args)`

[`function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) allows you to run a function with both a specific `this` value applied to it as well as passing in multiple arguments in an ergonomic way. Before we had [rest syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#rest_syntax_parameters), `function#apply` was the only approach to this, now you can actually just use `fn(...args)` in modern javascript (assuming you don't have to explicitly bind the `this` value of the function). Just keep in mind that `this` is an incredibly confusing concept for nearly everyone.

The reason why you would bind `context` in general in the function as defined, is just so that `debounce` is more generic and more capable of being called in different circumstances. For example, in this case, we can use `this` to increment a counter based on the element that the function was called on.

In practice, you wouldn't want the same debounced function put on both, you'd want to have one function and then debounce it twice, otherwise you could end up "canceling" a click on one by clicking on the other, but it's a good example of how `this` can make it more functional.

```js
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  var timer
  return function() {
    var args = arguments
    clearTimeout(timer)
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      fn.apply(this, args)
    }, delay)
  }
}


const debounced = debounce(function() {
  this.dataset.numClicks = (Number.parseInt(this.dataset.numClicks || 0)) + 1;
  this.innerText = `Clicked ${this.dataset.numClicks} Times!`
  console.log(this.innerText)
}, 500);
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', debounced));
```

```css
div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<button>Click me!</button>
<button>Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your very kind reply. However, I still don't understand why I bind this with the application and what exactly this is then bound. Can you explain a little bit more? @Zachary Haber

Comment: `this` is quite simply the context the function was called in, the issue is that you call `fn` within a different function instead of where it should've been called from, so you need to bind it with the `this` parameter of the outer function as that was the one called from the button (in the example I gave).

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy to see what the difference is when you test it out.

```js
function debounce1(fn, delay) {
  var timer
  return function() {
    var context = this
    var args = arguments
    clearTimeout(timer)
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      fn.apply(context, args)
    }, delay)
  }
}

function debounce2(fn, delay) {
  var timer;
  return function() {
    var args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      fn.apply(this, args);
    }, delay);
  };
}



var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', debounce1(function(){console.log("1", this);}, 500));
button.addEventListener('click', debounce2(function(){console.log("2", this);}, 500));
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```

You maintain the context of what triggered the function vs using the window object in the timeout.

Comment: Thank you for your very kind reply. However, I still don't understand why I bind this with the application and what exactly this is then bound. Can you explain a little bit more? @epascarello

Comment: Do you not see how the calling context changes? The one keeps the calling context as the button and the other one is the window object. So i you need to keep a reference, you need to maintain the scope.